# Not able to pass the values to model on click of a button in ngFor in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to pass the values from ngFor to model on click of a button But not able to find a way.I want to bind the ngFor variables to model.I searched in SO but did not find a solution.Please help.

Is it possible to do it?

enquiry.component.html

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Client Type:</label>
      <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.clientType" >
        <option>Business</option>
        <option>Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Number of Applicants:</label>
      <select class="form-control"  (change)="changeInApplicantCount(model.applicantCount)" [(ngModel)]="model.applicantCount" name="applicantCount">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
      </select>
    </div>

<div *ngFor="let applicant of fieldArray; let i = index">
   {{arryApplcnt[i]}}
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="usr">Applicant Title:</label>
  <select class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="applicant.applicantTitle">
      <option>Mr</option>
      <option>Mrs</option>
      <option>Dr</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">Applicant Surname:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="applicant.applicantSurname">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">Employment Status:</label>
  <select class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="applicant.employmentStatus">
      <option>Employed</option>
      <option>Self-Employed</option>
  </select>
</div>

</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" (click)="enquiryStep1()">Next</button>
</div>
```

In the typescript file I want to capture the data passed in the ngFor

enquiry.component.ts

```
Component({
  selector: 'app-enquiry',
  templateUrl: './enquiry.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./enquiry.component.css']
})
export class EnquiryComponent implements OnInit {


  arryApplcnt=["FIRST APPLICANT","SECOND APPLICANT","THIRD APPLICANT","FOURTH APPLICANT","FIFTH APPLICANT"];
  fieldArray=[0];
  model: any = {
    applicant:{}
  };


 changeInApplicantCount(x){
    console.log("x",x);
   this.fieldArray=[];
   console.log("empty",this.fieldArray)
    for(var i=0;i<x;i++){
      this.fieldArray.push(i);

    }
    console.log("Testing"+this.fieldArray);


  }


  enquiryStep1(){

    console.log("PAssed Data ",this.model);


  }

}
```

Comment: Your fieldArray only has one element, and instead of being an object with an applicantTitle, an applicantSurname and an employmentStatus, it's the number 0.

Comment: Please explain more what you want.

Comment: Initially the fieldArray will contain 1 element on change of that fieldArray to a different value like 2.The fieldArray will get populated with 2 values.On click of Next I want to capture the model values from the enquiryStep1 method from ngFor loop values like applicantTitle,applicantSurname and employmentStatus.